# npm run storybook fails on new react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, storybook

I'm trying to use Storybook for react.
I've created a new clean react app, and ran the following commands in the project folder cmd:

npm i -g getstorybook

getstorybook

npm run storybook

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./.storybook/config.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\project_folder\node_modules\babel-plugin-react-docgen\lib\index.js:89:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
 @ multi preview
```

The content of the config.js file is the default:

```
import { configure } from '@kadira/storybook';

function loadStories() {
  require('../src/stories');
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

node: v5.10.1

npm: v5.4.1

storybook: @kadira/storybook v2.35.3

Any clue as to what's wrong?

Comment: The error indicates that there is an unexpected token "=" in the file `./.storybook/config.js`. In order for us to help you, please show the content of this file.